# What's the auth code endpoint in Pinterest?

Tags: authentication, oauth, pinterest

This documentation is clear: http://developers.pinterest.com/api_docs/oauth_code_exchange/

I need the `code` for swap it with an access token. But where is the endpoint for access to this code? Tried the "classic" :

https://api.pinterest.com/oauth2/auth?client_id=&redirect_uri=&scope=&response_type=code

but seems 404.

Comment: I'm wondering the same. Have you found the answer to your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The endpoint for v3 is:

```
PUT https://api.pinterest.com/v3/oauth/code_exchange/
```

Example:

```
curl -X PUT https://api.pinterest.com/v3/oauth/code_exchange/ -d "access_token={access token}&consumer_id={client id}&consumer_secret={client secret}&redirect_uri={redirect uri}&code={code}&grant_type=authorization_code"
```

What is strange though, is that you have to pass in a valid access token for the endpoint to work or it will return an Unauthenticated error. The access token can be from anyone or any Pinterest app and does not need to be from the authenticating user or the authenticating app, as long as it has not expired.

The easiest way to obtain a valid access token as of now is to log in to the Pinterest for iPhone app here and you will find the token in the URL hash:

https://www.pinterest.com/oauth/?consumer_id=1431594&response_type=token

Comment: This sounds very strange! I need an access_token to get one? How will I (pragmatically) get a access_token to get access_token against the user? 

Also, `PUT` seems strange where it is `POST` for most (if not all)

Comment: so I did this:  curl -X PUT https://api.pinterest.com/v3/oauth/code_exchange/ -d "access_token={tokenFromiPhoneApp}&consumer_id={myConsumerId}&consumer_secret={myConsumerSecret}&redirect_uri={AppRedirectUrl}&code={codeFromInitialOAuthRequest}&grant_type=authorization_code", but I get "Something went wrong on our end. Sorry about that.", "data": "....", ....}

Comment: HI Guys 

When you get consumer id?
is app id consumer id?

I am trying using this way "https://www.pinterest.com/oauth/?consumer_id=1431594&response_type=token" but can not get success

https://in.pinterest.com/oauth/?consumer_id=4944452830850198488&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.recurpost.com%2Fconnectpinterestboardapi&response_type=code&state=RecurR01P0st1

Comment: is we need any implement or extra thing in our app side?
or need we I extra code on php side?

Answer (score 0):

In talking to the pinterest devs, this looks like the correct approach:

PUT https://api.pinterest.com/v3/oauth/code_exchange/?code={auth_code}&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id={client_id}&timestamp={timestamp}&consumer_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&oauth_signature={oauth_sig}

I was surprised to see that I would get a 401 when passing the data in the PUT body.