# Pinterest API v3 OAuth is it still working?

Tags: api, oauth, pinterest

Is Pinterest API still supported or they dropped the majority of the endpoints ?
The documentation from https://developers.pinterest.com/ lacks any information of OAuth authentication.
I've already checked the old versions of the API so please don't mark the question as duplicate:

> [How to Get OAuth Access Token for Pinterest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455388/how-to-get-oauth-access-token-for-pinterest)
>
> [pinterest api documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951045/pinterest-api-documentation)

Many of the endpoints from v2 were removed in v3 and v2 now returns 404.
There's no way to actually generate access token and the trick with iPhone app access token doesn't seem to work anymore.
The tasks I'm looking to accomplish with their API:

- authenticate users with OAuth
- upload pics on their boards based on access token

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use below link

https://www.pinterest.com/oauth/?consumer_id=1431594&response_type=token

and see

[pinterest api documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951045/pinterest-api-documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the new V3 documentation: https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/redoc/pinner_app

Assuming your app has been approved, the "User Authorization" section (https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/redoc/pinner_app/#section/User-Authorization) provides details on how to authenticate.