# Pinterest OAuth 2 - Asp.net C# gives error

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, pinterest

when i have try get code for access token with following link  https://pinterest.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=AppId
&redirect_uri=url.......
&scope=read

it's giving error

```
Something went wrong!
Sorry. We've let our engineers know.
Try Again?
```

and i have try get token following link
 https://www.pinterest.com/oauth/?consumer_id=1431594&response_type=token

When get Below error

```
SSL connection error

Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error code: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

please somebody help me how to get token of pinterest

Comment: See if the following can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455388/how-to-get-oauth-access-token-for-pinterest

Comment: I was try below API https://www.pinterest.com/oauth/?consumer_id=[client_id]&response_type=[code_or_token]&scope=[list_of_scopes]

but still problem give error  Something went wrong!